# Is there a way to add a singular lightbox modal for multiple images?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5, lightbox

I have multiple images that I am trying to make a fullscreen lightbox modal for. I have tried looking for lightbox modals but they all usually use jQuery and/or an older version of Bootstrap.

Currently I have tried this:

HTML:

```
          <div id="howItWorksSteps">
        <p>2) Customer select items to be included in quote.</p>
        <!-- 1 photo goes here -->
        <img class="myImg" src="images/MarketplaceSolution_3.jpeg" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"
        data-bs-target="#myModal">
        <p>3) Customer selects shipping options.</p>
        <!-- 1 photo goes here -->
        <img class="myImg" src="images/MarketplaceSolution_4.jpeg" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"
        data-bs-target="#myModal">
        <p>4) Customer requests a quote.</p>
        <!-- 1 photo goes here -->
        <img class="myImg" src="images/MarketplaceSolution_5.jpeg" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"
        data-bs-target="#myModal">
        <p>5) Seller responds to quote with confirmed prices and shipping costs of order.</p>
        <!-- 1 photo goes here -->
        <img class="myImg" src="images/MarketplaceSolution_6.jpeg" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"
        data-bs-target="#myModal">
        <p>6a) Customer pays for order.</p>
        <img class="myImg" src="images/MarketplaceSolution_7.jpeg" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"
        data-bs-target="#myModal">
        <p>6b) Seller updates order as paid.</p>
        <!-- 1 photo goes here -->
        <img class="myImg" src="images/MarketplaceSolution_8.jpeg" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;"
        data-bs-target="#myModal">
        <p>7) Seller updates customer with shipping details including tracking numbers.</p>
        <!-- 1 photo goes here -->
        <img class="myImg" src="images/MarketplaceSolution_9.jpeg" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:300px"
          data-bs-target="#myModal">


        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="multipleModalLabel"
          aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-fullscreen">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid p-0">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Javascript:

```
const divHowItWorks = document.getElementById("howItWorksSteps");
const howItWorksImgs = divHowItWorks.querySelectorAll("img");
howItWorksImgs.click(function() {
  const imageSrc = $(this).data('src');
});

const myModal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const currentImg = document.getElementById("image");
currentImg.attr('src', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lightbox.js` which makes life very easy. `data-lightbox="photos"` is the important bit in your HTML.

You will also need to get the `lightbox.js` file and `lightbox.css` file. These are available on [CDN right here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lightbox2).

```
<div class="thumbnailContainer">

  <a href="pic01.jpg" data-lightbox="photos"> <!-- Full photo -->
    <img class="img-fluid" src="pic01small.jpg"> <!-- Thumbnail / Small Clicker -->
  </a>

  <!-- Copy aditional pics here then place this entire Div inside your modal -->

</div>
```